# How to make data transfer to Google Drive faster?

Tags: python, python-requests, google-drive-api, python-multithreading

I have the following def, everything is working fine, but I want to try to make this process faster using the `ThreadPoolExecutor`

```
def update_tables():
            dir_path_1 = r'/home/.../'
            dir_path_2 = r'/home/.../test.json'
            SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    
            credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(dir_path_2, scopes=SCOPES)
            service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    
            # dir from Google Drive
            results = service.files().list(pageSize=100, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)", q="'1................P' in parents").execute()
            data = results['files']
            df = pd.DataFrame(data)
               
            # All
            for ii, i in zip(df['id'], df['name']):
                media = MediaFileUpload(dir_path_1 + i, resumable=True)
                r = service.files().update(fileId= ii,  media_body=media).execute()
                print(r)
 update_tables()
```

How can I transfer this function to `ThreadPoolExecutor` or insert `ThreadPoolExecutor` in a function? Perhaps there is another way to speed up data transfer? I will be grateful for help

Comment: You understand that the google drive api has flood protection.  You may want to check your quota and see what your requests per minute is.

Comment: @DaImTo, hi, yes of course, 10 requests by 1 sec from 1 IP-address (50,000 requests per day for 1 project). I need 2-4 requests for 1 sec

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/72399888/7108653